# In my spring login form url getting changed after submitting the form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

initially it is http://localhost:8080/HomeBankingSystem/login after submitting the form url coming as http://localhost:8080/signup
this is my controller

```
@Controller
```

public class HomeBankingController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(){
    System.out.println("###########################");
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String signup(){
    System.out.println("value################33");
    return "success";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your context path,

Into your login button add the next:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login">Login</a>
```

[EDIT]:

Here the answer to be more readable:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get Started</button>`
this is my login button

Comment: am doing form submit here ..how to that code @Ivan Lynch

Comment: thanks a lot ..now its working..but can u explain why v need to map like that..usually we will mention like /{pathname} right...??

Comment: Yes sure Yunanath, in this case your need to set your context path because your DispatcherServlet has configured the url mapping at "/" this mean the root directory if you change this to /HomeBankingSystem/ then you can use url i.e  /login without adding the context path.

If the answer is correct, mark as correct please.
Regards,

Comment: thanks for spending your valuable time for explaining me this .. :)